# Should I postpone my trip to Paris in 2nd week of Jan in light of recent protests?

Tags: france, safety, paris, event-based-effects

I’ve a date and I really waited long to make this happen. My gifrfriend is a bit worried about the security issue in Paris. Which locals think that the media is exagerrating the issue and the issue is small and non-threatening for tourists?

Comment: News channels are showing you 0.1% of Paris, focused on the worst parts at the worst time. 99.9% of Paris is unaffected.

Comment: Some major tourist attractions were compromised though...which is probably 0.1% of Paris too!

Comment: Paris's "tourist district" is *huge*. Protests are a blimp in comparison and they were only running for half a day or so.

Comment: I see. So you are saying by Jan 7 everything should be safe. I have accommodation 4km from Eiffel. Let’s hooe so. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Everything would be 100% safe unless you're literally living on the few streets where protests were active.

Comment: @JonathanReez Parisian here. The area affected by the protests last Saturday was unprecedented. I've never seen so many metro stations closed. Many museums will be closed tomorrow. The media only shows you the most spectacular parts, but for once, there were riots that a tourist could plausibly have gotten caught in.

Comment: Yes I’m concerned for what’s happening now but I’m not sure if it will be still unsafe in January ?

Comment: @JonathanReez: what are your sources? That's hard, even for French people and Parisians, to have a clear picture of the situation.

Comment: He is right about metro stations closing and big tourist areas being impacted. Source: BBC and pretty much every major new sources.

Comment: @Taladris my sources are seeing how protests in Western cities have played out in the past. News channels are feeding on showing you a highly manipulated image of what's really happening.

Comment: @JonathanReez: sure, the medias are not all reliable. But I see a problem with that reasoning: there are things happening in Paris and all over France. I don't believe in a "revolution" but some roads are blocked, public transportation is affected, there are fights between the Yellow Jackets and the police, and there are protests in touristic places (Champs Elysees, Arc de Triomphe,...). Saying that one should not believe the medias does not really help.

Comment: @Taladris if something serious is happening nearby you will know it from a mile away. Stay away from the core of the violent protests and you'll do just fine. As explained in an answer below the protests are only happening on one day per week anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: After Macron's recent speech, in which he caved into the demands of the protestors, do we expect Paris in the upcoming days,weeks or weekends to be more peaceful. How is the situation now?

Comment: @AliGajani Macron's speech on Monday hasn't been well received in France (a lot of people are saying “too little, too late”). Since the yellow jackets aren't an organization, there isn't a spokesperson who can say “it's over” or “it isn't over”, but most roadblocks haven't been lifted. Whether this will have any influence on Saturdays in Paris remains to be seen.

Answer (score 5):

The UK government's advice to UK nationals visiting France is here: https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france

The relevant part says:
"Protests against fuel prices continue across France, leading to blocked roads and motorways in some areas. You should avoid where possible and follow the advice of the authorities."

That is probably good advice for any visitor to any country experiencing some internal strife.

I used to live in France and never saw much in the way of protests except on TV.  Protests in France (and elsewhere in Europe) can be noisy and are well covered on the news channels; and there are sometimes incidents of violence. But if you stay away from them, you can enjoy your trip in other parts of the city and barely know there was anything amiss.

Comment: Sure but I saw they did graffiti on tourist areas too.

Answer (score 5):

The ***current*** situation in Paris, as of early December, is that there's a fairly large area on Paris that you should avoid on Saturdays. Everything is as usual on other days. (That's in Paris; in more rural areas, there are blocked roads. The blockades are mostly peaceful but they can make it harder to get around.) On Saturdays It's only a few hundreds of rioters amidst tens of thousands of peaceful protesters, but that's enough to be unpleasant if not dangerous if you get stuck between them and the police, and they sometimes move fast.

It may be difficult to understand which area to avoid as a non-local especially if you don't speak French; to get an idea, you can check [which metro and bus lines are not running](https://www.ratp.fr/en/travaux-manifestations/manifestations). That's in French, but all you really need to know is to avoid the neighborhood of the listed metro stations on the specified day. “*Trafic interrompu entre … et …*” means that the line is suspended between these stations. If a station in closed (“*fermée*”), you might see a mention “*Les correspondances restent assurées*” (the trains stop at an interchange station, but you can only change between lines, not enter or exit the station) or “*Les correspondances ne sont pas assurées*” (the trains will not stop).

That's the situation now. The situation is evolving rapidly, so it's impossible to make serious predictions as to what will happen in a month. However another month of protests at a scale that would affect tourists in urban areas would be extremely long, I don't find it very likely. Furthermore things are likely to quieten down for Christmas, and not likely to restart at the same scale. Road blockades may last longer but they wouldn't affect Paris.